# Accessing Azure AD groups using MSAL in React

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using a `create-react-app` based project that uses `react-aad-msal` to authenticate to Azure AD on the client. This is working correctly and I can retrieve basic user details after authentication. However, I'd like to limit access to the entire site to members of a specific AD group. All of my research has shown needing to use Microsoft Graph API to query AD, but that just seems like so much work to do something that should be more straightforward IMO.

My question is if there an easier way to do this? Can I somehow utilize claims through MSAL to achieve this? If not, is there a library that plays well with `react-add-msal` to simplify the process?